# Does Eclipse Milo Client SDK Support SCAN to Collect Data

Tags: milo

Similar to subscription do we have support for SCAN in the milo SDK client to collect the data? For SCAN, the timer will be at the client-side; for UA-Server, it is like a demand read. Please share more information about classes get used for SCAN.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/discussions/1018

> SCAN isn’t an actual OPC UA concept, but it sounds like you’re talking about issuing a periodic call to the Read service.
>
> You can do this, of course, but you’ll have to set up the timer yourself.